# Incorporate elements from input file name into figure title and figure file name in Python

Tags: python, matlab

My code iterates through multiple files using `glob`, produces a figure for each input file and saves them using `savefig`. I am trying to incorporate elements of the name of the current input file into both the title of the current plot and also into the name of the current output file. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046157/saving-figure-with-current-file-name-in-matlab) addresses how to use the current file name, but I do not wish to use the whole file name.

For example, say `200302182300_040842.oax` is the current file name, I would like to name the plot "`18/02/2003 2300UTC Atmospheric Conditions (sea breeze day)`" and the output file `18/02/2003 2300UTC Atmospheric Conditions (sea breeze day).png`   How can I divide up the input file name and use the different elements (e.g. year, month, day) within the plot title and output file name?

An example of the code I am using is below.

```
import glob
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

os.chdir('X:/stormdays')
for file in glob.glob("*.oax"):
    spc_file = open(file, 'r').read()
    try:   
        plt.title('140616/1900 (Observed) - Sea Breeze Day', fontsize=12, loc='left')
        plt.savefig('X:/stormgraph.png')


    except Exception:
        pass
```

Comment: Ok @David, please modified question, in which I have removed non-relevant code samples.

Comment: Much better! Without knowing python I can't answer your question, but it is much easier to understand now.

Comment: How do you get atmospheric conditions (like " Atmospheric Conditions ) (sea breeze day)" ) from the file name ? Or is it same for all files ?

Comment: @Nishant "atmospheric conditions" and "sea breeze day"  are just names that I would like to include in all titles and file names, but which are not derived from the input file names.

Comment: Since the first 4 characters of filename are year, next two are month, next two are date and so on, you can get these information programmatically via indexing, right ? But I am not sure on how will you open an oax file in matalb to plot.

Comment: @Nishant Yes, I had assumed indexing would be the idea, but I am not sure how to go about this. As for .oax format I have code that can read .oax format but I removed this from the sample provided because it was not relevant (as suggested by David).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the matlab code to do this. As you cannot have '/' in filenames, I am replacing it with '-'.

```
files = dir('C:\directory\.*oax')
for ind = 1:numel(files)
    filename = files(ind).name
    newName = [filename(7:8),'-',filename(5:6),'-',filename(1:4),' ',filename(9:12),' (Observed) - Sea Breeze Day','.png']
    figureHandle = figure()
    \\your code to plot 
    savefig(figureHandle,newName)
end
```

Python code (based on your code)

```
import glob
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

os.chdir('X:/stormdays')
for file in glob.glob("*.oax"):
    spc_file = open(file, 'r').read()
    try:   
        newName = file[6:8] + '-' + file[4:6] + '-' + file[0:4] + ' ' + file[8:12] +  ' (Observed) - Sea Breeze Day'
        plt.title(newName, fontsize=12, loc='left')
        plt.savefig('X:/' + newName + '.png')


    except Exception:
        pass
```

Comment: Is this matlab code at all transferrable to Python?

Comment: Hi @Nishant, had a couple issues getting going but now it's running perfectly. Thanks! Answer accepted.