# How to save the plotted figure automatically with source file name?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a matfile with data. I would like to plot the data and save as a figure with the same file name of the matfile.

```
clear all
%loading file
[file,path] = uigetfile
load(file);
```

```
% Plotting Processing
...
Plot(..,..)
hold off
legend show
```

Now i want to save the jpg file as same as the loaded file. which means file name stored in the variable file.

But the below code only save jpg as file.jpg.

```
%saving the figure
saveas(gcf,'file.jpg')
```

At starting of the code we need to select the file in order to load the data. that file name will be stored in the variable file.
e.g. file='test1.mat'

after plotting the data. I want to save the figure as test1.jpg. code has to do it automatically. Whatever matfile I choose, I should get jpg output with same matfile name.

Comment: no, it is not working.

Comment: Try saveas(gcf, strcat(erase(file, '.mat'), '.jpg'))

Comment: As an improvement of the previous suggestion, I think `saveas(gcf, strcat(extractBefore(file,'.mat'), '.jpg'))` would do what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving figure with current file name in MatLab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046157/saving-figure-with-current-file-name-in-matlab)

Comment: Have you considered using [live scripts](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-live-scripts.html)?

Comment: Thank you @avgJoe. It is working

Comment: thank you @tryman. Your code is also working

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Use the 'figure' call to set and get the figure's properties and plot your data.

```
f=figure;    %%your data will go after this for plotting
```

Save the image with the filename.

```
saveas(f, [File_Name '_.png'])  %% for saving the figure in PNG
```

PS: File_Name is the name of the file.